# How to send a correct HTTP PUT request in Java

Tags: java, http, http-put, philips-hue

I want to turn my lights off with Java using the Philips HUE Api.
For this, I have the following API: http://192.168.0.53/api/HZ3bJqN3MIb35uNcI4FfsGcqstwbW6qgvuxd7Tmt/lights/1/

This returns:

```
{
  "state": {
    "on": true,
    "bri": 178,
    "hue": 41044,
    "sat": 56,
    "effect": "none",
    "xy": [
      0.3313,
      0.3447
    ],
    "ct": 181,
    "alert": "select",
    "colormode": "ct",
    "mode": "homeautomation",
    "reachable": true
  },
  "swupdate": {
    "state": "noupdates",
    "lastinstall": "2020-07-03T12:17:24"
  },
  "type": "Extended color light",
  "name": "Hue color spot 1",
  "modelid": "LCG002",
  "manufacturername": "Signify Netherlands B.V.",
  "swconfigid": "9FD98F72"
}
```

Now I want to modify the "on: true" to "on: false" with Java. For that, I have this code:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.53/api/HZ3bJqN3MIb35uNcI4FfsGcqstwbW6qgvuxd7Tmt/lights/1/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
    requestBody.put("on", false);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(requestBody.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    // Debug
    int response = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(requestBody.toString());
    System.out.println(response);
```

This returns '200' and {"on":false} which would be perfect.
But for some reason, it just does nothing. The light remains on even though the connection exists.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't send"?

Comment: When you try to curl it via command line, both for on:true and on:false, what is the response code? e.g : curl -X PUT -d '{"on":true}' http://192.168.0.53/api/HZ3bJqN3MIb35uNcI4FfsGcqstwbW6qgvuxd7Tmt/lights/1/

Comment: I executed the command `curl -X PUT -d '{"on":false}' 192.168.0.53/api/HZ3bJqN3MIb35uNcI4FfsGcqstwbW6qgvuxd7Tmt/lights/1/state` both in the Windows Shell and the git bash (Linux). It worked in the git bash but not in the cmd.

Comment: @tgdavies I edited and tried to explain it better.

Comment: You need to have another api (Link) for edit.

Comment: No. I use this documentation: https://developers.meethue.com/develop/get-started-2/#findme2 

And according to this, this has to work.

Comment: When you say "it worked in the git bash...". What's 'git bash'? And do you mean that the lightbulb turned off?

Comment: With git bash I mean the command shell that you get when you instal git. Its just a normal linux command shell, so the curl command would most likely work in any linux shell. Also yes, I mean the lightbulb turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong URL for the PUT request.

A GET request to `http://192.168.0.53/api/.../lights/1` will return the current state

But to modify you need a PUT request to `http://192.168.0.53/api/.../lights/1/state`

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing, but don't know the Java part.

I got curl to work at the command level with triple quotes:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"""on""":false} http://192.168.0.53/api/HZ3bJqN3MIb35uNcI4FfsGcqstwbW6qgvuxd7Tmt/lights/1/state
```

This code will work with your hue lights, Please share the Java code with me when you get it to work. mike@toggle.is